# Loading Multiple jQuery Versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've written a tool that uses jQuery, and the tool is dynamically loaded on many different web pages, including ones that already use jQuery. I am trying to load jQuery on a web page that is out of my direct control. When I do so, Ajax calls that this page makes via jQuery stop working. The site, dailycaller.com, uses jQuery lazy image loading - when you scroll down the page, article images are dynamically loaded. When I attempt to load any jQuery version, this dynamic image fetching breaks. I suspect this is due to a version conflict between my loaded jQuery and the jQuery already on the page itself.

To test this, I tried loading the same version as the page does. The page includes a script tag

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn01.dailycaller.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
```

My JS code loads this version again (asynchronously, after the pageload), with

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.src = 'http://cdn01.dailycaller.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Even though this version of jQuery is, in theory, already on the page, this load causes the page's jQuery Ajax calls to break. How can I load an arbitrary jQuery version without breaking this page's dynamic loads?

I have tried using jQuery.noConflict() as recommended here [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) and it doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: Why do you need to load two versions at the same time?

Comment: see edit - I have a tool that uses jQuery and requires the latest version. It should be loadable from an arbitrary site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to allow the dynamically loaded copy of jQuery to finish loading before calling `.noConflict()`. Use the `onload` event on `<script>`.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Script:

```js
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.onload = function () {
    jQuery.noConflict( true ); //remove this and image load fails
};
script.src = 'http://cdn01.dailycaller.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks for illustrating the point that `appendChild` is an async call. Very helpful.

Comment: I guess I'm still wondering why loading the same version of jQuery that's already there breaks things on the page. Do you have insight there?

Comment: @EmmettJ.Butler Maybe loading two of the same version is killing the `$` variable. No idea.

Comment: I've been reading a lot of SO answers, but none of them deal with your point about using an onload callback. I'd suggest though that you edit your answer showing how to retain a "hook" on the noConflict version of JQuery that is returned. I think line 3 should read: `var myJQVer = jQuery.noConflict( true );`

Answer (score 4):

I have a quite similar issue on my webapp, there is a way to keep the previous version and use your own, even with plugins, here is what I do:

```
<!-- USING A NEWER VERSION OF JQUERY -->

<!-- store and protect the old one -->
<script>
var oldJQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<!-- load the new version and required plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../script/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../script/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../script/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../script/jquery.xml2json.min.js"></script>

<!-- store and protect the new one and put the old one back -->
<script>
var jQuerX = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery = oldJQuery;
</script>
```

it keep the old version unchanged, and you can use yours under the chosen alias (jQuerX).