# How to cope with Two versions of jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using Twitter BootStrap in an ASP.NET MVC 3 project. It uses **jquery-unobtrusive-validation.js** for Unobtrusive Validation purposes with **.live()** method implemented inside. jQuery file of version less than 1.7 is required for this to work because .live() is deprecated from version 1.7 onward.

For twitter Bootstrap, the **bootstrap.js** file has **.on()** method implemented inside which require jquery file of version 1.7+.

So finally the problem is, if I add **jquery-1.5.0.js**, bootstrap doesn't work properly and when I add **jquery-1.9.0.js**, unobtrusive validation doesn't work. How can I reference two jQuery files or how can I get rid of this issue? Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163468/loading-multiple-jquery-versions) thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js", change last line from:

```
}(jQuery));
```

to

```
}(oldJQuery ));
```

Now, you can use this old plugin like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../script/jquery-1.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- store and protect the old one -->
    <script>
    var oldJQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../script/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

    <!-- load the new version and required plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../script/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../script/bootstrap.js"></script>
```